# Java SSL error 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, ssl, spring-ws

Could someone help me to spot if there is anything wrong here with my SSLHandshake?

I have a Java client app (using Spring WS security) trying to send data to a server (not in my control) and I've setup the following

1. Client Truststore with certificate from the server
2. Java Keystore with my "PrivateKeyEntry" certificate & chains + certificate from the server (maybe that's not necessary)
3. Server has imported my public key associated with #2.

Below my debug SSL handshake log (some parts abbreviated), I can't seem to find any error.. is this something the server side need to look into? (I'm not sure, they are not sure, such the reason I'm asking here)

=====

```
...
loading bunch of truststore certs..
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom

%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1434719494 bytes = { 99, 87, 115, 11, 185, 203, 150, 154, 249, 227, 214, 17, 102, 68, 224, 171, 37, 125, 178, 169, 216, 111, 32, 118, 22, 231, 1, 135 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 73
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 98
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1347
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1434719497 bytes = { 210, 157, 0, 180, 231, 29, 218, 170, 155, 154, 158, 136, 171, 172, 173, 11, 9, 95, 169, 164, 107, 33, 138, 187, 114, 62, 39, 224 }
Session ID:  {86, 132, 21, 9, 10, 164, 177, 194, 128, 194, 233, 113, 113, 209, 137, 96, 86, 15, 246, 171, 126, 60, 182, 249, 58, 108, 215, 127, 171, 228, 223, 15}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
[abbreviated for simplification]...loads 
chain[0]
....
....chain[6]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
  [Abbreviated here for simplification]
]

Certificate Extensions: 6
[1]:  .... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
[2]: ..... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
[3]: ..... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
[4]: ..... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
[5]: ..... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
[6]: ..... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
.... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
.... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
Server Nonce:
.... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
Master Secret:
.... [Abbreviated here for simplification]
Client MAC write Secret:
...  [Abbreviated here for simplification]                             
Server MAC write Secret:
.....[Abbreviated here for simplification]                          
Client write key:
0000: 26 0E 02 DE 04 67 CF 56   79 17 FA 89 98 A3 D0 75  &....g.Vy......u
Server write key:
0000: 02 3E 5E 9D 7B C4 74 36   74 58 7E 64 D6 FF B4 2D  .>^...t6tX.d...-
Client write IV:
0000: 87 7B 42 7D 33 E9 2C E2   50 E8 49 FE 0C C9 FE 37  ..B.3.,.P.I....7
Server write IV:
0000: 4C 35 0F 1C F1 23 9F A3   49 21 5D 58 24 51 8F 9C  L5...#..I!]X$Q..
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 127, 65, 162, 165, 117, 87, 61, 139, 47, 253, 84, 93 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 198, 137, 122, 87, 73, 249, 126, 148, 111, 156, 34, 192 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 416
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 9520
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 192
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Forbidden [403]
```

Comment: I think the relevant portions of your Java code might help.

Comment: 403 means Forbidden... so start by looking at what endpoint you are working with... it's likely you aren't authenticated properly and/or have the wrong address.

Comment: Thanks @SankeDoc. That's what I original thought. The server side folks kept refusing to believe they did something wrong. I would like to think the address they gave me is correct..... Anyway, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

> SSL error 403

On the contrary. There is no SSL error here. 403 is an ***HTTP*** error code, and the fact that you received it indicates that your SSL setup is working perfectly.

403 means 'Forbidden', which means you're using a URL youve denied client access to under some or possibly all circumstances. Only you know what they are.

Comment: Thanks EJP.  I just wanted to make sure I have a pair of eyes who understand the SSL handhsake log and see if I missed anything.  So it does look like something happened on the server side.  I'd need to ask them to look into further as I did everything correctly here.